# android: how to handle onStop method call

Tags: android

If I have a method called `onStop` and it calls `super.onStop();`. When does this method run?

In my main activity, I start another activity as follows: `startActivity(new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class));`. Does this automatically stop my main activity and call `onStop`?

Also, what kind of things should I do in the `onStop` method of my main activity. So far all I have done is unregister listeners to free up space but other than that is there anything else I should do?

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my main activity, I start another activity as follows: startActivity(new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class)); Does this automatically stop my main activity and call onStop?

You can know yourself what happens when you call new activity takes focus just put a simple log statement and check yourself.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Quoting from the docs

When the current activity starts another, the new activity is pushed on the top of the stack and takes focus.

The previous activity remains in the stack, but is stopped. When an activity stops, the system retains the current state of its user interface. When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and the previous activity resumes (the previous state of its UI is restored).

`onStop()`

Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one. This may happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.
Followed by either onRestart() if this activity is coming back to interact with the user, or onDestroy() if this activity is going away.

Check the topic saving activity state

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ActivityState

Note: When the system stops one of your activities (such as when a new activity starts or the task moves to the background), **the system might destroy that activity completely if it needs to recover system memory**. When this happens, information about the activity state is lost. I believe this happens on priority basis.

If you need to store persistent data do it in `onPause`

For more info check the activity lifecycle

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 2):

```
When does this method run?
```

This method calls when your Activity is no longer visible to the user

```
Does this automatically stop my main activity and call onStop
```

Yes when you start another Activity first onPause() function get called and then onStop().

```
what kind of things should I do in the onStop method of my main activity
```

It depends on your implemenetation and your needs but persisting data recommended to implement on onPause() callback function